# Prolog: String data not displaying properly inside ELSE clause

Tags: prolog

I have a function that allows the user to enter a single quoted string (A), then searches a list of sublists (X) for the string and returns the sublist that contains the string:

```
process(6, X) :-
 nl, write('\tEnter student name or ID: '), 
 read(A),

 % FIRST WE CHECK FOR A in the ID SLOT
 member(  [A,B,C]  , X)

 % IF TRUE, DISPLAY DATA THEN PASS X back to menu
 -> write('\tID="'), write(A), write('", Name="'), write(B), write('", Grade='), write(C),nl,nl, menu(X)

 % ELSE, WE CHECK FOR A in the NAME SLOT
 ; write(A), write(' not found in ID slot'), nl, checkNAME(A, X). 

 checkNAME(A,X) :-
   member( [B,A,C]  , X )

   % IF TRUE (A in NAME SLOT)
   -> blah blah

   % ELSE
   ; blah blah
```

My issue is when i use variable A in the ELSE clause, i get junk data "L1_233" or w/e and this prevents the ELSE clause from working properly. I tried to create a copy of A and use it in the ELSE clause, but all it does is create a copy of junk data. Why does variable A work in the IF CLAUSE but not the ELSE? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're having an operator precedence issue.

In Prolog, "AND" (the comma) has a higher precedence than `->`. So the `nl, write(...), read(A)` is all considered part of the first half (antecedent) of `->`. If the antecedent fails, then Prolog will backtrack to a point before `read(A)` and `A` won't be instantiated if the "else" path is taken. You need to parenthesize:

```
process(6, X) :-
 nl, write('\tEnter student name or ID: '), 
 read(A),

 % FIRST WE CHECK FOR A in the ID SLOT
 (  member(  [A,B,C]  , X)

 % IF TRUE, DISPLAY DATA THEN PASS X back to menu
 -> write('\tID="'), write(A),
    write('", Name="'), write(B),
    write('", Grade='), write(C),
    nl,nl, menu(X)

 % ELSE, WE CHECK FOR A in the NAME SLOT
 ;  write(A), write(' not found in ID slot'),
    nl, checkNAME(A, X)
 ).
```

"AND" (comma) is also higher precedence than "OR" (semicolon) so parenthetical grouping isn't needed for the consequent and else AND sequences.

Comment: thanks a lot. always something simple that keeps me staring at my PC for hours.